# How to detect a change of active object?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I would like to perform some action, programmed in Python, when the user changes the active object. How can I get this information?

Comment: Depends what is the user action on active object you want to listen to. Look at these answers: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19524/python-basics-interactive-script, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19668/execute-a-python-function-whenever-the-user-interacts-with-the-program